# Excel VBA. Memory leak when running EntireColumn.Delete

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Excel VBA script where I loop through the sheets in a WorkBook, and delete some columns to make a summarized version of the book.

I delete columns with this command:

```
Columns(columna).EntireColumn.Delete
```

My Loop is nothing special:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         For I = 1 To WS_Count
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
            MyFunction            
         Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Inside MyFuntion I have:

```
'I delete 3 columns in each sheet
Columns("E:G").EntireColumn.Delete 'Memory leak exactly here!
```

The first time I run this command in a Sheet, this causes a memory spike, and after looping through about 10 - 12 sheets, the system runs out of memory and throws an not enough resources error.

I've tried this in several machines and excel versions (2007,2013)

Is this a normal Excel behaviour? How can I avoid this memory leaks?

**UPDATE**
For the moment, as a workaround, I can recover some memory if I save the WorkBook (ThisWorkbook.Save) after processing every few sheets. This makes my script much slower, but at least does the job.

Definitely there is a memory leak in all Excel versions when deleting a column. Most of the solutions proposed are just other ways to delete them, but this should be unnecessary IMO when we have a simple command like

```
Columns(columna).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: You should post the loop you are using.

Comment: Try to change the variable name from `column` to another name like `MyColumn`.

Comment: Are you trying to always delete column E, F, and G? If so, you can use `Columns("E:G").EntireColumn.Delete`. Also. you can use `Application.ScreenUpdating`.

Comment: Basically Yes, but there's more. I delete EFG because there is content in BC. Then I test if there is data in IJ, and delete LMN, and like that till I have no more data. But the first call to "EntireColumn.Delete" causes the leak, so I guess this is not relevant.

Comment: Have you tried the above code? Also you can use the `With` statement. `With Worksheets(i)` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate` remember `End With` the line after `myfunction`

Comment: No luck Niclas.. this ideas are not working. I stil have the memory leak.

Comment: How many worksheets are you looping through?

Comment: any difference with manual calculation and disabled events ? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-functionality-during-macro-execution#t=201611210031441514186

Comment: Or try to use an array instead. `ReDim WS_Count(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) <newline>

For i = 1 To UBound(WS_Count) <newline><your code here>

Next`

Comment: try this:`Sheets.Select
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
  Columns("E:G").Select
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`

Comment: With the error coming out when processing the 10-12 worksheet, it seems relevant what the function does before deleting the columns, I suggest to include that function in the post....

Comment: I'm betting this is a problem with something on your function that you overlooked.

Comment: I have been hitting this issue too. Simply calling Range.Delete on a small range (4x9 cells on average) causes a 100MB jump in memory usage. I have conditional formatting, which i suspect is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    '' If still having memory spikes try uncommeting the .Calculation lines too
    '' (There's also one at the end)
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    MyFunction ws:=ws
Next ws

With Application
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

---

```
Public Sub MyFunction(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Range("E:G").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

This gets rid of the use of `.Activate` which is an extra overhead which you don't need whilst doing this and also declares the range explicitly

Comment: no luck. Still memory leak after implemeting all of this. I even added more features from https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/25/best-way-to-improve-vba-macro-performance-and-prevent-slow-code-execution. Also avoided .Activate

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is an Excel bug.

I worked around it by creating a new sheet and copying over the data i want to keep, then deleting the original sheet.

Alternatively, you could also copy everything from column H onwards and paste it in column E, then `.Clear` and `.ClearFormatting` on your last 3 columns that are now empty.